Apple IIe Enhanced not following BEQ correctly
I'm running the example code from Assembly Lines chapter 5 programs 2A and 2B which print the entire character map for the Apple II and then are supposed to break, however my code is looping permanently. Here is the code:
      ORG $300
HOME  EQU $FC58
CTR   EQU $06
COUT  EQU $FDED

START JSR HOME
      LDA #$FF
      STA CTR
LOOP  LDA CTR
      JSR COUT
      DEC CTR
      BEQ END
      JMP LOOP
END   RTS

I have double checked the book and don't think I mistyped anything but the program just loops over and over, almost like the zero flag isn't ever properly set. I know the zero flag works for dex and dey because I've used those for loop counters in prior exercises.
Thanks!

Not an Apple programmer, but my first thought is - does DEC set the condition codes?  I've used computers where "SUB #1" and "DEC" are not identical.

I see what you're saying - the zero flag may be getting cleared by DECing the memory before checking the BEQ condition. I'll swap those and see if it makes a difference. Thanks for the suggestion, dave!

@Justme I think that's a typo and that you meant N and Z, the latter of which is what BEQ checks.

Check that COUT equate - I'm not familiar with the specific assembler you're using here (I'm a KickAssembler user) but I suspect whatever the JSR #FDBD instruction is being assembled as, it's not what you think and the DEC afterwards isn't being executed. Have a look at the assembler output to see what opcodes it produced. Also, get yourself a good debugger so you can single-step the code and watch register values as it executes.

@Eight-BitGuru I do know the dec is happening because without it the character printed to screen would not be changing - the dec both decrements the loop & the character to be printed. Still puzzling this one.
I am using Merlin Pro 2.43 :) Heard good things about KickAssembler though.

You should include that information in the question, really. Anyway, try putting an LDA #00 after the DEC to force the Z flag to zero. If the loop doesn't terminate on the BEQ then the problem lies elsewhere. I still say you should check the actual assembler output to see what opcodes are actually being generated though.

Program looks good. 1) would that 06 address changed by the COUT routine maybe? try to change CTR address. 2) remove the JSR COUT part and see if it finishes like this.

Example 2b uses $FDED for COUT. Otherwise, the code works fine. Are you running it from the monitor or merlin or what?

DEC xxx updates Z flag all right. This is a false lead. In your example, why HOME address starts with $ and COUT with # BTW??

@Jean-FrançoisFabre because I accidentally mistyped :D in the on-disk source they're both $addresses. I had to manually transcribe to Stack Exchange and goofed :D

@KelvinSherlock I have tried BRUN and running 300G from monitor, both have the same issue. I'll see if FDED has any impact on the code.

Hey @Jean-FrançoisFabre I will try your suggestions before bed tonight and revert back.

For those who come here scratching their heads, this is explained later in Assembly Lines - I was attempting to BRUN the assembled code, however that struggles with properly exiting when printing some control codes using COUT specifically. The solution was to BLOAD the code and then run it with CALL 768. Loops just fine now. Not a code error at all but a quirk of the Apple II Monitor.

The debuggers in modern emulators can be very helpful when something seems to go off into the weeds.  See e.g. https://6502disassembly.com/applewin-dbg.html

Perhaps you can incorporate this circumstance into the question?
